# Add views to Toolbar

Tags: android

I've searched for this question but haven't found a useful answer yet.
I am trying to create a Toolbar with some kind of edittext inside of it.
It should look like this:

[image]

How should my XML file look like? Currently it looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/activity_main_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/title"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:textSize="22sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</LinearLayout>
```

The activity looks like this:

```
private Toolbar toolbar;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.acitivty_main);

  toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewbyid(R.id.activity_main_toolbar);

  setSupportActionbar(toolbar);
```

}

But the result is some Edittext which is right in the center of the Toolbar, letting no space for the toolbar title (please ignore the "save" menu button)

[image]

Now my question is,

1. How do I correctly add one or more views to the toolbar **below** the main actionbar height?
2. Could you recommend me some example or tutorial page?
3. What kind of EditText is used in the shown image with the floating hint?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well first I think it easy to answer the second and third question first, you can find that information in the "Android Developer Blog" in "Android Design Support Library". Here the link:

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015_05_01_archive.html

Just scroll down till you find the section called "Floating labels for editing text" and sorted.

Now for the first question, what I did was I made a "Toolbar" layout (won't be able to elaborate too much here as I'm busy at the moment) and then added it to the layout. The code is below:

**Toolbar Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- NOTE: Use To Maintain Structure Of Actionbar -->
<Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#009688"
    android:id="@+id/toolBar"
    android:elevation="2dp">
    <!-- NOTE: Required For Top Section Structure -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <EditText
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="@string/note_title"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/actionTitle"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            style="@style/ActionText"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textDate"
            style="@style/ActionDate"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</Toolbar>
```

**Adding it to the Layout File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- NOTE: Layout For Edit Note Activity -->
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <!-- NOTE: Assigned Custom Toolbar -->
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        layout="@layout/tool"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And that should sort you out (You can then mess about with the actionbar properties to clean it up aka: getActionBar().setElevation(0); and 
getActionBar().setTitle("");